# How to run rules on accounts with specified ExchangeStoreType?

Tags: vba, outlook

I am setting up automation for multiple email accounts that my team monitors.

I created my own rule for an individual account. I have done some googling and editing to get it to work for multiple accounts.

It is listing accounts I do not want.

I want to set variables for all the outputs, so I can then run rules on specific accounts.

```
Sub RunTest()
Dim storeRules As Outlook.Rules
Dim storeRule As Outlook.Rule
Dim allStores As Outlook.Stores
Dim myStore As Outlook.Store

Set allStores = Application.Session.Stores
For Each myStore In allStores
    On Error Resume Next
    Debug.Print myStore.DisplayName & "  " & myStore.ExchangeStoreType
    Set storeRules = myStore.GetRules()
    For Each storeRule In storeRules
        'storeRule.Execute ShowProgress:=True' 'disabled until code is working'
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

The output of the Debug Log is: (**** covers sensitive information)

```
Public Folders - ****@****.com.au  2
****  1
****  1
**** ****  1
**** **** ****  1
**** ****  1
****@****.com.au  4
****  1
****@****.com.au  0
Public Folders - ****@****.com.au  2
```

I want to run rules for **4** and **0**. How do I set variables for individual items in what is effectively an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the `myStore.ExchangeStoreType` conditions.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub RunTest_ExchangeStoreType()

Dim storeRules As Rules
Dim storeRule As Rule
Dim allStores As Stores
Dim myStore As Store

Set allStores = Session.Stores

For Each myStore In allStores
    
    'On Error Resume Next
    'If needed, place just before the expected error.
    'Follow closely with On Error GoTo 0 to return to normal error handling.
    
    Debug.Print myStore.DisplayName & "  " & myStore.ExchangeStoreType
    
    Select Case myStore.ExchangeStoreType
    
        Case 0, 4
            Debug.Print " ExchangeStoreType matched: " _
              & myStore.DisplayName & "  " & myStore.ExchangeStoreType
            
            Set storeRules = myStore.GetRules()
            For Each storeRule In storeRules
                'storeRule.Execute ShowProgress:=True' 'disabled until code is working'
            Next
    
    End Select
    
Next

End Sub
```